# install package manager on asus router

Tags: package-management

I just got an [asus dsl-ac68u modem/router](https://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLAC68U/) and I noticed it has ssh access. I set this up and I can ssh in with root permissions, but it doesn't seem to have a package manager installed. Being used to Debian, just to test, I tried:

```
# apt-get install vim
```

but got the following response:

```
-sh: apt-get: not found
```

**how can I figure out if there is a package manager installed?** i thought about trying to find out the distro that is running, but I can't even figure that out:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.36.4brcmarm (sam@SW5-Server-50) (gcc version 4.5.3 (Buildroot 2012.02) ) #10 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 14 16:24:32 CST 2015
# uname -a
Linux (none) 2.6.36.4brcmarm #10 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 14 16:24:32 CST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
# ls /etc/*elease*
ls: /etc/*elease*: No such file or directory
# ls /etc/*ersion*
ls: /etc/*ersion*: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be some customized version of Linux, and not any particular distro. **how can I install `apt` on such a device?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only within a chroot using debootstrap, if the architecture is supported.  Don't mess up the real filesystem.  I believe this approach has been popular on certain NAS devices, e.g. http://www.rooot.net/en/geek-stuff/synology/39-chroot-debian-synology-debootstrap.html

The router will <strike>almost</strike> certainly not be designed to alter the filesystem (treated as ROM).  Hence the lack of package manager.  This means your chroot will have to be in tmpfs or a mounted usb device.

tmpfs will obviously not survive reboots :).  And won't be big enough to reliably run debian.  You'll have to use a usb storage device.

You may wish to participate in openwrt development for your device.

- http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/asus/rt-ac68u
- https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=51005
- https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=52378

Looking at the specs there's enough ram to have some fun with, and the processor looks good too so a Debian chroot on usb might just be an option.  However remember that in this case you will be limited by the original kernel+modules, which may not be intended for your desired uses.

Answer (score 5):

As you can find out on [WikiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_DSL-AC68U) or [Asus's website](http://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLAC68U/), this router runs [AsusWRT](http://www.asus.com/Networking/DSLAC68U/ASUSWRT/). AsusWRT is a derivative of [Tomato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_(firmware)) which is itself one of the descendants of [HyperWRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperWRT), a Linux distribution for low-end network appliances such as routers.

With only 8MB of flash, you aren't going to be able to install extra software there. However, there is a USB port where you can plug in storage media, and run code from there.

With the original Asus image, you can install additional programs through [Optware](http://dsl-n55u.wikidot.com/optware). Optware comes with the package manager [`ipkg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipkg).

You may also be interested in the community firmware [asuswrt-merlin](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki).

I don't recommend attempting to install Debian packages as the device is pretty limited (only 64MB of RAM). Get a package source that targets smaller devices, even if it means learning a new package manager.

Comment: If you want to use `ipkg` you will need `/opt/` to all be setup. This can be achieved by enabling the Download Manager on the USB drive. This will then create all the necessary symlinks

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki/Entware

> [Entware](http://github.com/Entware/entware) is a modern alternative to Optware. Originally designed
>   for OpenWRT, it is also usable by other firmware platforms such as
>   DD-WRT or Tomato. You can also set this up on your Asuswrt-Merlin
>   based router.
>
> ....
>
> The easy way Starting with v3.0.0.4.270.25 a new script has been
>   introduced to facilitate Entware installation. After installing a USB
>   drive (Do Not Install DownloadMaster), just type in terminal:
>
> ```
> entware-setup.sh
> ```

Then, you can

```
opkg list
opkg install software_name
opkg remove software_name
```